# Delimiter problem with Biblatex-DW: Remove comma from citation

Tags: footnotes, delimiters, biblatex-dw

I am currently working on individualising the Biblatex-DW style to work for my PhD thesis needs. So far I got some problems solved by myself, but the current problem causes me real headache since I am not that used to the code.

The final citation style for all types of documents should be:

> [author last-name smallcaps] ([year]), [page number without prefix].

So far I got:

> [author last-name smallcaps], ([year]) [page number without prefix].

I filled out most of the fields of the to make sure no field is printed in the citation which does not belong there.

Here is my attempt of a MWE:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{acronym}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
    \usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib} 
@misc{bar_zitiertest_2004,
  title = {Zitiertest Dokument 2 Autoren},
  shorttitle = {Krzttl},
  author = {Bär, Gold and Rahmen, Bilder},
  date = {2004-05-19},
  publisher = {{Verlag}},
  url = {www.url.aub},
  urldate = {2020-01-13},
  abstract = {Zusammenfassung},
  langid = {deutsch},
  note = {Extra}
}

@mvbook{baum_zitiertest_2006,
  title = {Zitiertest Buch 3 Autoren},
  shorttitle = {Krzttl},
  author = {Baum, Tannen and Zange, Kneif and Kopf, Schafs},
  date = {2006-05-19},
  edition = {7},
  volume = {1},
  publisher = {{Verlag}},
  location = {{Ort}},
  url = {www.url.de},
  urldate = {2020-01-13},
  abstract = {Zusammenfassung},
  isbn = {0815},
  langid = {deutsch},
  note = {Extra},
  number = {55},
  pagetotal = {999},
  series = {Reihe},
  volumes = {2}
}

@incollection{eis_zitiertest_2004,
  title = {Zitiertest Buchteil 5 Autoren},
  shorttitle = {Krzttl},
  booktitle = {Warum Schneemänner keine Heißgetränke zu sich nehmen sollten ...},
  author = {Eis, Schoko and Tasse, Kaffee and Salat, Kartoffel and Duck, Donald and Mann, Schnee},
  date = {2004-05-19},
  edition = {1},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {999},
  publisher = {{Verlag}},
  location = {{Ort}},
  url = {www.url.aub},
  urldate = {2020-01-13},
  abstract = {Zusammenfassung},
  isbn = {0815},
  langid = {deutsch},
  note = {Extra},
  number = {45},
  series = {Reihe},
  volumes = {9}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    style=footnote-dw,
    annotation=true,
    edstringincitations=true,
    idembib=false,
    library=true,   
    namefont=smallcaps,
    shorthandibid=false,
    xref=false,
    abbreviate=true,
    backref=false,
    bibwarn=true,
    ibidtracker=false,      
    idemtracker=false,
    isbn=false,
    maxnames=3,
    natbib=true,
    sorting=nyt,
    sortlocale=auto,
    url=false,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}

    \addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{geometry}   
    \geometry{margin=3cm}                   

\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

%Last names only in citations:
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}

%Getting rid of fields/lists/names in citations:
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{abstract}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{afterword}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{annotation}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{annotator}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{annote}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{authortype}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{bookauthor}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{bookpagination}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{booksubtitle}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{booktitle}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{chapter}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{commentator}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{crossref}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{day}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{edition}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{eventtitle}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{howpublished}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{issue}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{journal}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{journaltitle}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{key}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{note}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{number}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{organization}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{pages}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{publisher}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{school}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{series}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{shorttitle}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{type}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{urldate}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{urlyear}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{volume}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{volumes}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{address}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{institution}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{location}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearname{editor}}%
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearname{journal}}%

%Getting rid of >in:<:
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{in = {}}

%Putting the date into parens for the citation & undoing it for the bibliography again:
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{#1}}

%Getting rid of the page prefix:
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{%
\iffieldpages{postnote}{\addspace}{\addspace}}

\begin{document}

Citation nr. 1\cite[19]{bar_zitiertest_2004}\newline
Citation nr. 2\cite[13-56]{baum_zitiertest_2006}\newline
Citation nr. 3\cite[2-3]{eis_zitiertest_2004}

   \printbibliography 
   \end{document}
```

Happy to correct mistakes and answer questions ASAP
 - Flo

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Thank you for posting a fully working example document. I haven't had a very close look at what you are doing yet, but I'm wondering why you are using `style=footnote-dw,`, which gives full citations in the footnotes, and then delete almost all info with `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{...}}`. It seems easier just to start with an author-year style like `style=authoryear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`footnote-dw` is a style of the 'verbose' family that prints the full bibliography entry in footnote citations. What you want is more of an author-year style. It appears very complicated to try and get a verbose style to be an author-year style because it amounts to deleting almost all information for the citations. That can be quite cumbersome.

It would be nicer to just take a style like `authoryear` as your citation style. Generally, `biblatex` allows you to select different `bibstyle` and `citestyle` values. Unfortunately, the styles of the `biblatex-dw` bundle can not be easily combined with arbitrary other styles not from the bundle, since there is a strong dependence between citation and bibliography style. So a solution like `bibstyle=footnote-dw, citestyle=authoryear,` does not work.

If you want to stick to a `biblatex-dw` style, I think the easiest solution is to take `authortitle-dw` as a basis and modify its citation commands to become an author-year style instead of an author-title style. As it turns out that is actually doable without too much work.

We just need to load `style=authortitle-dw,` then we need `labeldateparts=true,` so that `biblatex` provides `labeldate` information. The redefinitions of `cite:title` and `cite:title:force` should be self explanatory. We also modify `cite:edstringincitations`
to use the correct delimiter.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authortitle-dw,
    sorting=nyt,
    labeldateparts=true,
    maxnames=3,
%
    annotation=true,
    edstringincitations=true,
    idembib=false,
    library=true,
    namefont=smallcaps,
    shorthandibid=false,
    xref=false,
    abbreviate=true,
    backref=false,
    bibwarn=true,
    ibidtracker=false,
    idemtracker=false,
    isbn=false,
    natbib=true,
    url=false,
]{biblatex}


\DeclareDelimFormat[footcite,smartcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:edstringincitations}{%
  \ifbool{cbx:edstringincitations}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:editorstrg/translatorstrg}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labeldate}{%
  \ifbool{cbx:parens}
    {#1}
    {\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{review}}
    and
    not test {\iffieldundef{xref}}
  }
    {\printtext[review]{\bbx@review{\thefield{xref}}}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title:force}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}

\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\bibmultinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\citemultinamedelim}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\addspace}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{bar_zitiertest_2004,
  title      = {Zitiertest Dokument 2 Autoren},
  shorttitle = {Krzttl},
  author     = {Bär, Gold and Rahmen, Bilder},
  date       = {2004-05-19},
  publisher  = {Verlag},
  url        = {www.url.aub},
  urldate    = {2020-01-13},
  abstract   = {Zusammenfassung},
  langid     = {ngerman},
  note       = {Extra}
}
@mvbook{baum_zitiertest_2006,
  title      = {Zitiertest Buch 3 Autoren},
  shorttitle = {Krzttl},
  author     = {Baum, Tannen and Zange, Kneif and Kopf, Schafs},
  date       = {2006-05-19},
  edition    = {7},
  volume     = {1},
  publisher  = {Verlag},
  location   = {Ort},
  url        = {www.url.de},
  urldate    = {2020-01-13},
  abstract   = {Zusammenfassung},
  isbn       = {0815},
  langid     = {ngerman},
  note       = {Extra},
  number     = {55},
  pagetotal  = {999},
  series     = {Reihe},
  volumes    = {2}
}
@incollection{eis_zitiertest_2004,
  title      = {Zitiertest Buchteil 5 Autoren},
  shorttitle = {Krzttl},
  booktitle  = {Warum Schneemänner keine Heißgetränke zu sich nehmen sollten \dots},
  author     = {Eis, Schoko and Tasse, Kaffee and Salat, Kartoffel
                and Duck, Donald and Mann, Schnee},
  date       = {2004-05-19},
  edition    = {1},
  volume     = {5},
  pages      = {999},
  publisher  = {Verlag},
  location   = {Ort},
  url        = {www.url.aub},
  urldate    = {2020-01-13},
  abstract   = {Zusammenfassung},
  isbn       = {0815},
  langid     = {ngerman},
  note       = {Extra},
  number     = {45},
  series     = {Reihe},
  volumes    = {9}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Citation nr. 1\autocite[19]{bar_zitiertest_2004}

Citation nr. 2\autocite[13-56]{baum_zitiertest_2006}

Citation nr. 3\autocite[2-3]{eis_zitiertest_2004}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bär; Rahmen (2004), 19.//Baum; Zange; Kopf (2006), 13–56.//Eis u.a. (2004), 2–3.]

Comment: Dear moewe, that did the trick! Cheers mate! Since my style requirement told me to use footnotes all along, I was somehow mislead and aimed for footnote styles only. My effort clearly put the cart before the horse. The citations work like they should now but I guess this will not be my last issue. Is it wise to ask further questions related to the code above in here or should I open another topic? Best - Flo

Comment: @FloE Please ask new questions about that (except if you have a question specifically about the code in the answer, in that case a comment here should suffice). If you ask a new question, please keep the question focussed on one issue per question.